# Showing $ \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2}]$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Here i want to prove
\begin{align}
  \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2}] = \{ a + b \sqrt[4]{2} + c \sqrt[4]{4} + d \sqrt[4]{8} \mid a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}\} 
\end{align}
this is a field. To do that i want to prove
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{a + b \sqrt[4]{2} + c \sqrt[4]{4} + d \sqrt[4]{8}} \in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2}]
\end{align}
Is there any ideas for showing this?

---

[edit] Many of you prove $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2}]$ is a field in indirect way. Is there any ways for showing this in direct way? For $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$, using some formulas i can check that indeed every nonzero elementn is unit. But this case does not seem that easy...

Comment: Why dont you write $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2}]=\{a+b\sqrt[4]{2}|a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ which makes it much easier?

Comment: @Cornman ...because that's not true?

Comment: Why not? It is $b\sqrt[4]{2}+c\sqrt[4]{2}+d\sqrt[4]{2}=(b+c+d)\sqrt[4]{2}$, with $(b+c+d)\in\mathbb{Q}$, since $b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}$, so you can also write $b+c+d=e\in\mathbb{Q}$ Edit: Oh, I see. There are other facotrs... Is this really how this field is defined?

Comment: @Cornman I don't understand your comment.  Anyway, you can't write $\sqrt[4]{4}$ (or $\sqrt[4]{8}$ for that matter) as a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combination of $1$ and $\sqrt[4]{2}$.

Comment: @Cornman : I don't think you've noticed there are three different radicands in the original expression.

Comment: Yes, I noticed this now... Sorry.

Comment: @Cornman, if you have a root $\alpha$ of irreducible polynomial $f$ of degree $n$, then $\mathbb Q[\alpha]$ is a field of dimension $n$ over $\mathbb Q$ with base $\{1,\alpha,\ldots,\alpha^{n-1}\}$.

Comment: @phy_math : We gave you all the methods. None of them is indirect !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idea: use that $\sqrt[4]{2} = \sqrt{ \sqrt{2}}$, so first rationalize to a denominator in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, and then finish off.

$$\frac{1}{a+b \sqrt[4]{2} + c \sqrt[4]{4} + d \sqrt[4]{8}}= \frac{1}{a + c \sqrt{2} + (b + d \sqrt{2}) \sqrt[4]{2}}= \\
=\frac{a + c \sqrt{2} - (b + d \sqrt{2}) \sqrt[4]{2}}{(a + c \sqrt{2})^2 -\sqrt{2}(b + d \sqrt{2})^2}$$ and rationalize by amplifying the fraction by $(a - c \sqrt{2})^2 +\sqrt{2}(b - d \sqrt{2})^2$

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty standard and proved in most abstract algebra textbooks. Let $\alpha=\sqrt[4]{2}$ then $\alpha$ is root of $f(x) = x^{4}-2$ and this polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q} $. The expression $$\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt[4]{2}+c\sqrt[4]{4}+d\sqrt[4]{8}}$$ can be written as $1/g(\alpha)$ where $g(x) = a+bx+cx^{2}+dx^{3}$ is a polynomial of degree $3$ or less with rational coefficients. Since degree of $g$ is less than that of $f$ and $f$ is irreducible, it follows that the polynomials $f, g$ are relatively prime to each other.  In other words their GCD is $1$. Therefore there exist polynomials $a(x), b(x) $ with rational coefficients such that $a(x)f(x) +b(x) g(x) =1$. Putting $x=\alpha$ and noting that $f(\alpha) =0$, we see that $b(\alpha) g(\alpha) =1$ or $1/g(\alpha)=b(\alpha) \in\mathbb {Q} [\alpha ] $.

---

The argument above applies for any field $F$ and any element $\alpha\in K\supseteq F$ which is algebraic over $F$. Under these conditions $F[\alpha] =F(\alpha) $. In fact more is true: $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$ if and only if $F(\alpha) =F[\alpha] $. The proof given above is based on the fact that $F[x] $ is an Euclidean domain with all the nice properties of GCD.

---

It is precisely this particular proof which left a deep impression of abstract algebra on me. Before this I used to think that abstract algeba consisted of boring axioms and playing around with them and that the classical theory of equations was the real algebra. For me this was the first non-trivial result where the classical manipulation techniques failed and GCD came to the rescue.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 1):

Through the magic of upper triangulation and backsubstitution...

\begin{align*}
      \frac{1}{a + b \sqrt[4]{2} + c \sqrt[4]{4} + d \sqrt[4]{8}} &= e + f \sqrt[4]{2} + g \sqrt[4]{4} + h \sqrt[4]{8}  \\
\iff  1 &= (a + b \sqrt[4]{2} + c \sqrt[4]{4} + d \sqrt[4]{8})(e + f \sqrt[4]{2} + g \sqrt[4]{4} + h \sqrt[4]{8})  \\
        &= (ae + 2bh + 2cg + 2df) \\ &\qquad + (af + be + 2ch + 2dg)\sqrt[4]{2} \\ &\qquad + ( ag + bf + ce + 2dh )\sqrt[4]{4} \\ &\qquad + ( ah + bg + cf + de )\sqrt[4]{8}  \\
\iff \{ 1 &= ae + 2bh + 2cg + 2df,  \\
        0 &= af + be + 2ch + 2dg,  \\
        0 &= ag + bf + ce + 2dh,  \\
        0 &= ah + bg + cf + de \}  \\
\implies \{ h &= \frac{-bg - \dots}{a}, \\
            g &= \frac{-bf- \dots}{a}, \\
            f &= \frac{-be- \dots}{a}, \\
            e &= \frac{a^3-2 a \left(2 b d+c^2\right)+2 c \left(b^2+2
   d^2\right)}{a^4-8 b d \left(a^2+2 c^2\right)-4 a^2 c^2+8 d^2 \left(2 a
   c+b^2\right)+8 a b^2 c-2 b^4+4 c^4-8 d^4} \}  \\
\implies f &= \frac{-b \left(a^2+2 c^2\right)+2 d \left(2 a
   c+b^2\right)-4 d^3}{a^4-8 b d \left(a^2+2 c^2\right)-4 a^2 c^2+8 d^2
   \left(2 a c+b^2\right)+8 a b^2 c-2 b^4+4 c^4-8 d^4}  \\
\implies g &= \frac{-a^2 c+a b^2+2 a d^2-4 b c d+2 c^3}{a^4-8 b d
   \left(a^2+2 c^2\right)-4 a^2 c^2+8 d^2 \left(2 a c+b^2\right)+8 a b^2 c-2
   b^4+4 c^4-8 d^4}  \\
\implies h &= \frac{-d \left(a^2+2 c^2\right)+2 b \left(a
   c+d^2\right)-b^3}{a^4-8 b d \left(a^2+2 c^2\right)-4 a^2 c^2+8 d^2
   \left(2 a c+b^2\right)+8 a b^2 c-2 b^4+4 c^4-8 d^4}
\end{align*}

Maybe this isn't the best way to go...

Comment: How did you compute those coefs (see my answer) ?

Comment: @reuns : Exactly as indicated.  Upper triangularize: solve for $h$ and sub into other expressions, then solve for $g$ and sub into other expressions, then solve for $f$ and sub into other expressions, then solve for $e$.  This last will have no $f$s, $g$s, or $h$s.  Now backsubstitute into $f$, then into $g$, then into $h$.  This gives everything in terms of $a$s, $b$s, $c$s, and $d$s.  (Aside:  I made Mathematica do the actual algebra, but I organized the computation as described.  Asking Mathematica to brute force it is too slow.)

Comment: Ok. I'd say at first you are computing the matrix representation $A$ of $\alpha$ (seen as a linear map $x \mapsto \alpha x$ on the $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2}]$) then you are computing its adjugate matrix (Gaussian elimination) by hand, and at the end your denominator is $\det(A) = N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha)$. The Galois conjugates of $\sqrt[4]{2}$ I used in my answer lets us diagonalize $A$ and compute its inverse easily.

Answer (score 1):

So take any element of $Q[\sqrt[4]{2}]$. It will be algebraic over $Q$. You write down the algebraic equation. Say it looks like $x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_0=0$ with $a_0\in Q$. Define $g(x)=x^{n-1}+a_{n-1}x^{n-2}+\dots+a_1$. Then $x(g(x))=-a_0$. Note that $a_0$ is invertible. So you have found the inverse of $x$ by $a_1^{-1}g(x)$ by simply plugging in $x$ value of that element.

Comment: Well, the $a_k$ depend on $x$ ! And I'd mention $\sqrt[4]{2}$ is algebraic so $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2}]$ is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space so for any element $\alpha \in\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2}]$, $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, which implies $\alpha$ is algebraic with algebraic relation $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k \alpha^k = 0, a_0 \ne 0$ and what you said $\alpha^{-1} = -\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \alpha^{k-1} \in \mathbb{Q}[\alpha] \subset \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2}]$ follows.

Comment: @reuns Ah. Yes. My bad. I did forget to mention as I thought this should be obvious from first step. My bad. It is the same recipe to cook things up.

Comment: Also with $\alpha = \sum_{m=0}^3 b_m \sqrt[4]{2}^m$ then the Galois conjugates and the field norm or the adjugate matrix formula mean $\alpha^{-1} = \sum_{l=0}^3 c_l \sqrt[4]{2}^l$ where the $c_l$ are rational functions of the $b_m$ (example : $\frac{1}{a+ib} = \frac{a}{a^2+b^2}-i\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}$)

Answer (score 1):

Let $R = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2}]$.

To show that $R$ is a field, rather than trying to directly show that
$$\frac{1}{a + b \sqrt[4]{2} + c \sqrt[4]{4} + d \sqrt[4]{8}} \in R$$
for all $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q}$, other than $(a,b,c,d) = (0,0,0,0)$, instead show that $R$ is isomorphic to some ring which is clearly a field.

Thus, consider the principal ideal $(x^4-2)$ of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

It's not hard to prove that $x^4-2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Hence, since $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a PID, it follows that $(x^4-2)$ is a maximal ideal, so $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^4-2)$ is a field.

Next, consider map $f:\mathbb{Q}[x] \to R$ defined by $f(p(x)) = f(p(\sqrt[4]{2}))$.

Argue that $f$ is a surjective homomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ onto $R$, with kernel $(x^4-2)$.

It follows that $R$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^4-2)$, hence $R$ is a field.

Of course then it follows, without actually computing the inverse that
$$a + b \sqrt[4]{2} + c \sqrt[4]{4} + d \sqrt[4]{8}$$
is a unit of $R$, for all $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q}$, other than $(a,b,c,d) = (0,0,0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $$\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}[2^{1/4}], \qquad \alpha = \sum_{m=0}^3 b_m 2^{m/4}, \qquad b_m \in \mathbb{Q}$$
[Then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm) $$N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha) = \prod_{k=1}^4 (\sum_{m=0}^3 b_m (i^k 2^{1/4})^m) \in \mathbb{Q}$$
(proof : it is invariant by $2^{m/4} \mapsto (i^k 2^{1/4})^m$, where $i^{k} 2^{1/4}$ are the other roots of $x^4-2$)

And hence for $\alpha \ne 0 \implies N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha) \ne 0$
$$\alpha^{-1} = \frac{\prod_{k=1}^3 (\sum_{m=0}^3 b_m (i^k 2^{1/4})^m)}{N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha)} =  \sum_{l=0}^3 c_l 2^{l/4} \in \mathbb{Q}[2^{1/4}]$$
where the $c_l $ are rational functions of the $b_m$.